# Vscode shows fake import errors when saving a file | Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle, syntax-highlighting

After saving/modifying the file, vscode highlighting an error importing my com.papersaccul into visual studio code
Despite the fact that gradle.build specifies the path

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
    }
}
```

If I switch to another window and switch back, the errors disappear.
The application works fine, built via gradle

[after ctrl+s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkmsX.png)

[after switch window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdw18.png)

jetbrains doesn't have that problem.

I think the problem is in the standard java debugger (vscjava) even though I've kind of configured the build through gradle in .vs

Comment: Try `Ctrl+Shift+P --> Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace`

Comment: I have made an answer. If you accept it, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Restart vscode after using the following command:**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace`